# How to log ALL queries made by users in SQL Server 2017 Standard?

Tags: sql-server, audit, sql-server-2017, logs

Is there a possibility to do this? All queries and actions performed in any database need to be logged, because of in house compliance.

I need information (and/or source) if we need MS SQL 2017 Standard or Enterprise in order to ensure that the DB Admin's activities (run, modify, etc queries...) are logged and not only the activities performed by non-admin users.

Comment: That would be either tracing (using either extended events directly or SQL Trace) or SQL Server Addit (which sits on top of Extended Events). At least those are the means that comes with SQL Server. Be prepared for lots and lots of logs.

Comment: The key is that even admins need to be logged, is this possible?

Comment: @jsterr, as tibor karaszi said "be prepared for a lot and lots of logs", I remember I logged the results of sp_whoisactive to a table for every 30s and then after few weeks the entire table was like 120 gigs!

Comment: Thanks! Is tracing / logging part of Common Criteria Certification so Enterprise Certification is needed or am I fine with sql 2017 Std.

Comment: @jsterr, are you talking about the version of sql server (mainly edition)?

Comment: @Bijujose yes right

Comment: No, the type of functionality I mentioned is available in lower editions. CC is something different. So you are fine to start evaluating your options using Std Ed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Common Criteria Compliance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/common-criteria-compliance-enabled-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017) is an enterprise feature

In the standard edition, well any edition,  you can create a trace and trace "Audit Schema Object Access Event" that will give you a statement level audit. You can then filter on objects or databases to minimize the logs and create the trace as [a server side trace](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqldbauk/2010/03/14/setting-up-a-server-side-trace/).

The Audit Schema Object Access Event seems not to be accessible using extended events but the server side trace can be set up to stop the server if logging is no longer possible and is detailed enough to be acceptable as a compliant audit for PCI requirements

As I am corrected below, in later versions of SQL Server you can setup a database audit in all editions and audit all statements against a database or specific objects.

Comment: "fined grained audit" is available in lower editions as of 2016 sp1.

Comment: Only as a server audit, if you want to audit at the database level you need the enterprise edition (https://www.logbinder.com/Blog/?p=d1f5efd3-d0a8-4c3e-82a5-6c8fc7e7f672)

Comment: No, you are linking to an old article. Check the official doc and you will see that "Fine grained auditing" is available across all editions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-2017